# HYPERLINK cell with querystring - works in open office, not in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a CSV (| delimited) with the following column:

|=HYPERLINK("http://www.mysite.com/folder/lookup.aspx?p=4000000")|

When I open this in the Open office version of excel, I click it and it takes me to that URL

If I do the same in Excel 2007 (Mac or Windows), it goes to www.mysite.com.

Why is excel stripping the querystring? How can I stop this?

(I have found nothing on Google).

Thanks.

UPDATE

Some other relevant info - the link links into a site that requires login. If I paste the URL into the browser directly (while logged in) in it works fine.

if I click the URL - it just directs to the base URL with no querystring or page (whether the user is logged in or not).

Comment: I obfuscated the link - the real link works when you copy paste it. Also just updated question

Comment: The same setup (import csv, http link, basic authentication) works for me. Figure out what request the web server receives when you click the link, opposed to when you enter it in the browser.

Comment: How can I figure out the request the web server receives? Does your link contain a querystring and require login to that area?

Comment: Did not use query string.

Comment: How can I figures out the request the web server receives?

Comment: Inspect the logs if you control the server. If not, you have to use a http-sniffer, which may be overkill in your situation. Or just set up a dummy server for this purpose.

Comment: I just tried it with Excel 2010 on Windows 7 with a URL having a query. On clicking the hyperlink internet explorer opens with the correct url. Also the request is made at the web server with the intact query.

Comment: Hi. Did that page require a login? I think it is because mine requires a login. Even if I am logged in it still doesn't work (see UPDATE above)